# Mongoid timestamp is missing

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I'm trying to use mongoid timestamps in my model class to update the `created_at` and `updated_at` fileds. However, these fields are missing in DB for all inserts and updates.

That's how I'm upserting documents:

```
update_hash = { :$set => some_hash_1, :$setOnInsert => some_hash_2}

application = Application.where(external_id: external_id)
application.update(update_hash, upsert: true)
```

However, when I'm trying to update this way, it works:

```
application = Application.find_or_initialize_by(external_id: external_id)
application.update_attributes!(update_hash)
```

I don't want to use the second method as it makes 2 calls to the DB. How can I make the first one working? Am I doing something wrong or it could be some mongoid bug?

This is how my model class looks like:

```
class Application
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :external_id, type: String
  ...

end
```

mongoid version is 7.0.4.

Comment: With that low-level update method you have to pass the `created_at` / `updated_at` fields yourself.

Comment: @Stefan there's another way to do this with higher level method but with 1 DB operation?

Comment: I'm not aware of any. But it should be a matter of adding `some_hash_1.merge(updated_at: Time.current)` and `some_hash_2.merge(created_at: Time.current)` (didn't try though)